# Which is the best practice for splitting a package in an OSGi-modularized bundle?

Tags: java, jar, osgi

The use case I have in mind is fastutil, a large library comprising thousands of implementations of type-specific collections. The library is popular and used by almost 500 Maven projects, but many user consider its size (>10K classes) unmanageable and have asked for splitting the jar in smaller pieces.

The jar currently is OSGi-modularized as follows:

```
Automatic-Module-Name: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil
Bundle-Name: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil
Bundle-SymbolicName: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil
Export-Package: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.*
Bundle-Version: ${version}
```

I would like to split this jar in three pieces (and, just to be clear, a contributor created the information above—I know little about OSGi). The problem is that necessarily the split will involve splitting packages—there's no way to avoid that due to the nature of the library. I have read a lot of articles discouraging this practice, but this is our only option. It is my understanding that in this case one should use `Require-Bundle`, which allows to split a package between bundles.

I have not found, however, examples of this practice *for a previously existing bundle*. In this case, we would like this modification to go through the users transparently.

Imagining a split in two jars, my current understanding would be to use the following modularization: the core jar would use

```
Automatic-Module-Name: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.core
Bundle-Name: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.core
Bundle-SymbolicName: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.core
Export-Package: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.*
Bundle-Version: ${version}
```

and then the rest of the jar would be modularized as

```
Automatic-Module-Name: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil
Bundle-Name: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil
Bundle-SymbolicName: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil
Require-Bundle: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.core
Export-Package: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.*
Bundle-Version: ${version}
```

This seems reasonable, but now the bundle name of half of the package is different from the module name of the other half. Can this cause problems?

More generally, for the use case above (already OSGi-modularized jar that needs to be split across packages), what is the best practice?

Comment: The only practice I know is to not split packages. Every package should come from exactly one bundle.

Comment: It is not clear if you did the down vote of my answer? Would be nice to provide a comment in that case.

Comment: I've came across a similar issue, I did not solved it yet. But there's a possible workaround with [bundle _fragment_](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/osgi-demystified-part-4-dont-bungle-your-bundles/#don-t-split-your-packages).

Answer (score 1):

> More generally, for the use case above (already OSGi-modularized jar that needs to be split across packages), what is the best practice?

If you're having the described problem that you've *not* modularized anything. On the contrary. Modularization's purpose is to create highly cohesive modules that interact through well defined interfaces. Your proposal indicates that this idea behind modularity is not well understood.

Splitting up a large library because it has too many classes is doing the worst thing in modularity possible. You increases coupling and decrease cohesion. You make something horrible like jackson where you always need 6 bundles on your classpath.

For modular systems, the packaging is a primary design aspect, it is not something you can start thinking about afterwards. If you, you do not reap the enormous benefits of modularity and you'll likely be fighting OSGi all the way. OSGi is the sweetest of environment for modular apps, but it is a bitch for others.

If you're serious about modularity then you should try to decompose the packages in such a way that each sub bundle has higher cohesion and the overall coupling is decreased. This significantly reduces complexity.

There are techniques like Tarjan's algorithm that can analyze your code and find the natural module boundaries. Most often the big mess is caused by supporting other optional libraries but coding in such a way that they become mandatory transitive dependencies. I always get very sad when I need to compare some troubled company's classpaths.

That said, but doubt this is in play, using well designed service APIs can usually make the far majority of classes private, especially when designed with Configuration admin in mind.

The conclude, if you're having problems with OSGi it is likely because it is telling you that you're not working modular.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, splitting a package is a bad practice. There is no best practice on how to do it. That said, it does happen that people need to split an overgrown package into pieces at some point. I would point you to Eclipse which has done this on several occasions. See https://www.eclipse.org/equinox/documents/3.2-migration.php for a discussion of one example: the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` package. I will also observe that the Eclipse IDE is not a best practices example of using package export/import due to its overuse of Require-Bundle.